# SQL statement check for concatenated value and return statement if not found

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to search a two column table with a CustomerID and a ServID. The primary key is the combination of both. I want the query to search if the combination is there. If it is return something I can use in c# to cancel the input or if it is not found have it insert the record. This is as far as I have made it after hours of searching.

```
IF (SELECT * FROM Cus_Ser WHERE customerID=inputnumber AND ServID=inputnumber) IS NULL
   PRINT 'Already Exists'
ELSE
   INSERT INTO Cus_Ser(CustomerID,ServID) VALUES(inputnumber, inputnumber)
```

Here is the code

```
@using WebMatrix.Data
@{
var CustomerID = Request.QueryString["CustomerID"];
var ServID = 0;
var db = Database.Open("Azure");
var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Customer INNER JOIN Cus_Ser ON Customer.customerID=Cus_Ser.customerID INNER JOIN Service ON Cus_Ser.ServID=Service.ServID WHERE customer.CustomerID =" + CustomerID);
var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);
var selectedData2 = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Service");
var grid2 = new WebGrid(source: selectedData2);

if (IsPost)
{ if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["ServID"], out int numbertest))
    {
        ServID = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["ServID"]);
        var dbCommandSearch = "SELECT * FROM Cus_Ser WHERE customerID=" + CustomerID + " AND ServID=" + ServID;
        //search = db.QuerySingle(dbCommandSearch);
        //if ((CustomerID, "ServID") != search    
        db = Database.Open("Azure");
        var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO cus_ser (customerID,ServID)VALUES(" + CustomerID + ", " + ServID + ")";
        db.Execute(insertCommand);
        Response.Redirect("~/ViewService?CustomerID=" + CustomerID);
    }
    //else
    //{
    //Validation.AddFormError("Entered Value is Not a Service Numberr");
    //}

    else
    {
        Validation.AddFormError("Entered Value is NOT a Service Number");
    }
} }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Add Service</title>
<style>
    .validation-summary-errors {
        border: 2px dashed red;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 12px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
<legend>Input Service To Add</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="ServID">Service ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ServID" value="@ServID" />
        </p>

        <input type="hidden" name="CustomerID" value="@CustomerID" />

        <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Submit Changes" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<p><a href="~/ViewCustomers">Return to customer listing</a></p>
```

Comment: Which dbms????????????????????????????

Comment: Just use a stored procedure to do both. Insert if the PK doesn't exist or return already exists to the C# and then prompt the user for an action.

Comment: I am using Azure to host the server and database and also do my query testing. WEI_DBA can you give me an example of what that would look like or where I would do that. I am sure new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multiple Inline SQL Statements**

Your sample code seems to be very close. The `QuerySingle` method will return null if no matches are found. Thus you can check for a null value  before issuing the insert statement, with something like:

```
ServID = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["ServID"]);
var dbCommandSearch = "SELECT * FROM Cus_Ser WHERE customerID=" + CustomerID + " AND ServID=" + ServID;
search = db.QuerySingle(dbCommandSearch);
if (search == null) { // record does not already exist
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO cus_ser (customerID,ServID)VALUES(" + CustomerID + ", " + ServID + ")";
    db.Execute(insertCommand);
    Response.Redirect("~/ViewService?CustomerID=" + CustomerID);
}
else
{
    Validation.AddFormError("Entered Value is Not a Service Numberr");
}
```

**Single SQL Statement**

You can combine this all into one big SQL statement, something like:

```
var sql = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Cus_Ser WHERE customerID=@0 AND ServID=@1)
              SELECT 0 as [Inserted];
            ELSE
              BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Cus_Ser(CustomerID,ServID) VALUES(@0, @1)
                SELECT 1 as [Inserted];
            END";
```

You can execute this as a parameterized query, which is much safer* than the code you have:

```
var response = db.QuerySingle(sql, CustomerID, ServID); // passing the input value as a parameter
if (response.Inserted == 1) { 
    // WebMatrix might convert to a bool, in which you would want `response.Inserted == true` instead
    Response.Redirect("~/ViewService?CustomerID=" + CustomerID);
}
else
{
    Validation.AddFormError("Entered Value is Not a Service Numberr");
}
```

As I am not deeply familiar with WebMatrix, I am not 100% sure about this code. Hopefully it sets you in the right direction.

---

A word of warning: your original code is vulnerable to something called a SQL injection attack. Most programmers start out making that mistake; I know that I did. In summary: that `inputnumber` parameter could have a SQL statement in it instead of a number. If someone crafts that SQL Statement just right, then they could cause a lot of damage. For an entry-level programming assignment it is not something to worry about in detail. But as you progress in coding, you will need to learn how to use parameterized queries in order to guard against SQL injection. A few useful references:

- [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
- [Introduction to Working with a Database in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about 2 things. The first is why do you declare the variables in the dbo statement (I declared them at the beginning of the c# program. Do I need to do it again?) The second is with the SELECT 0 and 1 as [INSERTED] statements. Can you elaborate on what those do?

Comment: The sample code you have does not make clear how you are embedding the SQL into C#. When I saw `inputnumber` it appeared to be a generic placeholder for a real number. PRINT statements are not generally helpful with C# code - only with SQL that you run through SQL Management Studio (for example). The structure of your example led me to think you wanted a stand-alone script, which could be run through C# or by itself - this stored procedure example provides that. If you want something simpler in C#, it will help to show your C# code as well.

Comment: Sorry I am new to both coding and stackoverflow. Below is my code. The idea is that the you get to the page by linking from a customers page. Then you can add services by typing in a service number. It works if I enter a service number the customer doesn't have and I have it return and error if what the person enters in the field is not an integer. The program crashes if I try to put in a service they already have.

Comment: I will try to take a look soon.

Comment: I got it work using your method where the query returns a single column result of Customer ID with the first entry being 0. How can I convert that result to a string or Int so I can say if result != 0 then insert else throw error message? I am using WebMatix.Data if that matters

Comment: I've updated my response based on the new information.

Comment: @DaneLooman if this solution worked for you, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!